# Convert List of ArrayList of Objects into Object [][]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Do anyone have an idea how to convert 2 dimension List:

```
private List<ArrayList<Object>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

into array: `Object [][] data;` ? 
I noticed that data.asList(`new Object[i][j]`); is returning only 1 dimension like `T[]`. Of course j dimension is always constant.

Comment: Use a loop. And inside this loop, transfor each inner list into an Object[].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a for loop and call [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) for each inner list.

```
Object[][] arr = new Object[data.size()][];
int i = 0;
for(ArrayList<Object> list : data){
    arr[i++] = list.toArray();
}
```

With [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you could map each inner list to an array and then construct the resulting array:

```
Object[][] arr = data.stream().map(List::toArray).toArray(Object[][]::new);
```

Comment: Thank You very much. It totally solved my problem. I will also try with 1.8 features, It will force me to see new features for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to loop over all the arrays in the list like this:

```
Object[][] objs = new Object[data.size()][];
for(int i= 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    objs[i] = data.get(i).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using Java8's streams ?

```
    data.stream()
            .map(il -> il.stream().toArray(size -> new Integer[size]))
// OR THIS  .map(il -> il.toArray(new Integer[0]))
            .toArray(size -> new Integer[size][]);
```

1. stream - do something like iterator and goes through all elements (all Lists)
2. map - transfer element (List) into what you want (Array[]). While List could be streamed you do same, but you could use Arrays
3. toArray - you transfer you stream and finalize it.

Here is whole Main method with some example data

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(Arrays.asList(10, 11, 12, 13));
    data.add(Arrays.asList(20, 21, 22, 23));
    Integer[][] result = data.stream()
            .map(il -> il.toArray(new Integer[0]))
            .toArray(size -> new Integer[size][]);
}
```