# adding a list to an empty list of lists

Tags: java, list

How can I add a list to an empty list of lists?

Like:

```
static int[][] Pos = new int[][2]; //this actually don't work
// list1 = [0, 1]; list2 = [2, 3]
Pos.add(list1); 
Pos.add(list2);
```

"Pos" should return this:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You don't have a List of List.

Comment: You need to work on your syntax too... `[0, 1]` isn't valid Java.

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like lists...

Comment: `new int[][2]` also isn't valid Java syntax.... You have to provide sizes for both brackets

Comment: @ElGavilan So I put a list into your list of lists, so you can add to list while adding to list

Comment: @user3580294 No actually you can leave the second empty. `int[][] a = new int[2][];` is valid.

Comment: @ZouZou That's new, never saw that before. Wonder what that produces...

Comment: @user3580294 You just specify that you create a 2D array but you don't specify the length of the sub arrays. So you can do something like `a[0] = new int[3]; a[1] = new int[4];`. It can be pretty useful when you don't know the length of the subarrays, like in this [case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324347/convert-list-of-arraylist-of-objects-into-object/23324401#23324401) per example. =)

Comment: @ZouZou Interesting... I'll keep that in mind for future use. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From your current code, you want to initialize an array of arrays of `int`s.

```
static int[][] Pos = new int[2][];

static {
    int[] array1 = { 0, 1 };
    int array2 = { 2, 3 };
    Pos[0] = array1; 
    Pos[1] = array2;
}
```

More info:

- [Java Tutorials. Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), specifically Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array section.

---

In case you want/need real `List`s, you may use one of these approaches:

You're looking for a `List<Integer[]>`:

```
static List<Integer[]> Pos = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

static {
    Pos.add(new Integer[] { 0, 1 } );
    Pos.add(new Integer[] { 2, 3 } );
}
```

Or a better option: `List<List<Integer>>`:

```
static List<List<Integer>> Pos = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

static {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(0);
    list.add(1);
    Pos.add(list);
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    Pos.add(list);
}
```

Comment: probably some glitch or you fixed that already. Never mind.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a list of lists.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> pos = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
pos.add(list1);    
pos.add(list2);
```